# Compositor - ERROR : Mask 'Mask' not found when added via spacebar search

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking

**ERROR** (in the Compositor):

> Mask 'Mask' not found

**CONTEXT**: I get this error In any new project, when I try to add the Mask Node in the compositor, (EDITED2403) **using the " spacebar " to find the " Add mask node "**

- When I open an older project(1) using the mask node, the node works.
- If I copy and paste it from an older project(1)  in a new project(2) it works (in the same blender session)
- In an older project(1) using the Mask Node, I can add another Mask Node without error.
- In a new project(2), where I've past the Mask Node from an older project, I can't add the Mask Node (You can see it in the screen capture). But I can copy / paste the Mask Node, and it works.

*(1) created with 2.76b*

*(2) tested with 2.76b, 2.77, 2.77RC2 portable version*

**What I've tried (without success)**:

- I've deleted all folders and files in the Roaming/Blender Foundation/ folder.
- I've un-installed/re-installed Blender (2.77 to 2.76b)
- I've un-installed/re-installed Blender (2.76b to 2.77)
- Same thing with a Blender 2.77RC2 portable version.
- Reset to factory settings

[image: blender showing the error in the info window]

Comment: Can you post the file you are having issues with?

Comment: Hi cegaton and ty for your interest. Well, i don't have a specific file with that problem. I get the problem with ANY new project :(

Comment: Here's something to test. You can add the node a different way. [Set up a custom keyboard shortcut for it like this.](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=100941) Test it both with and without the "Use Transform" option on. I don't think it will make a difference, but it's one thing I would try if it were me.

Comment: Also, have you tried File > Load Factory Settings ? I know you've reinstalled but, just in case it's something with your startup file...

Comment: Hi Mentalist and ty for your interest :) Well i've just tried to reset to the factory settings but unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. I will try the custom keyboard shortcut and give you the feedback

Comment: Ok i've just realized that i've missed to say something i was thinking it wasn't important ... In all of my tries, i've NOT used the Add function but the spacebar to find the " Add Mask Node " as the result of the search.

Comment: I can confirm that it always return an error message (the one we can see in the picture). And effectively, when i use SHIFT A > INPUT > MASK ... it works ...

Comment: I'm really sorry and confused now. I've really appreciated your help guys :) But maybe it stays a real bug with that " spacebar " search method. i presume i should modify the initial post and to precise  how i've REALLY got the error. My bad, sorry again, and have a nice day :)